# Java Process is not killing using wmic

Tags: batch-file, wmic

I need to kill java process from a batch file I am using command

```
Wmic Path win32_process Where "CommandLine Like '%MyApp.jar%'" Call Terminate
```

I got the output at cmd "No Instance (s) Available"

Comment: yes i have used taskkill with windowtitle but is some time not kills the process and double instanse of apllication created

Comment: can i get process ids of a running jar??

Comment: i am doing complete process from batch file